# Comma before nonessential clause ending a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

Is it correct to place a comma before a nonessential relative clause ending a sentence? For example

> I met Katherine Jankowski, who is a world-renowned engineer.

Is the comma here correct?
I have been to told to avoid commas between an independent and a subordinate clause:

> I took the bus because my car broke down yesterday.

not

> I took the bus, because my car broke down yesterday.

Is this also correct?
I thank all helpers.

Comment: The comma in your first example is *totally* fine. In your second example it's optional at best—a matter of style, so to speak.

Comment: @user405662 thank you, I was told to avoid commas in the second example

Comment: Sometimes the comma can change the meaning. "I took the bus which traveled on Ballarat Rd." distinguishes that bus from a different one. "I took the bus, which traveled on Ballarat Rd." gives extra information about the bus I took, which may be the only one.